# It were cucumbers or It was cucumbers

Tags: grammar

everyone!

Please, help me with these simple but unexpectedly  complicated sentences!

Here they are:

My grandmother planted **something** in her garden. **It was** cucumbers /  **It were** cucumbers.  (Which one is correct?)

My grandmother planted **vegetables** in her garden.  **????** were cucumbers.

As my brother told me when we use **something** (singular) in the sentence, we can use **IT** in the beginning of next sentence.

But when we use **vegetables** (plural), it is weird to use **it** but maybe **it were** is appropriate.

So, what do you think? Thanks in advance for answers!

P.S. I've seen the topic about **if it were**, but I think my story is different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [That's a lot of \_\_\_ vs. those are a lot of \_\_\_](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/218582/thats-a-lot-of-vs-those-are-a-lot-of)

Comment: "It was cucumbers"; "They were cucumbers".

Comment: *It was cucumbers which cured him*. *They were cucumbers which you saw growing in the field*.

Comment: Possibly best approached by looking at the 'cleft sentence' structure: _It was the tigers that really excited him._ /  _It was cucumbers that she planted in her garden._ Never 'It were ...'; your first follow-on sentence echoes this structure. //// The second follow-on sentence uses referential 'they' as anaphor after the antecedent 'vegetables'.

Answer (score 1):

A singular noun becomes *it* when referred to by a pronoun; a plural noun becomes *they*.  I am sure you know this, but it is the only grammatical point your question raises.

More interesting is why some apparently plural nouns are in fact singular. *Vegetables* is normally plural (lunch may include two vegetables, and you eat *them* without worrying about the fact that one is a single potato, while the other is four carrots), although if the canteen gives you unidentified 'vegetables' by the spoonful, you eat *it*. So your second sentence should certainly contain *they*.

The first sentence should equally clearly contain *it*, to agree with *something*; equally clearly it sounds odd. This is because your choice of words was slightly odd to begin with. If your grandmother planted 'something' it would normally be a single plant; if she had six bushes to put in, she would plant *some things*. (You can certainly turn it over to lawn, in which case you put in *grass* or *clover* in the singular; but you don't *plant* a crop like that, you sow it.) So by saying "She planted something", you are implying that it was (in this case) a patch of cucumbers rather than twelve individual seeds.